# How to persist variable value from inner class (Response.Listener) to the outside?

Tags: java, android, android-volley, inner-classes, gson

I have this function called `facebookCheckEmail()` (below) inside a container class, and I want to change a variable value (`fbresponse`) of the container class inside `public void onResponse(FbCheckObject fbCheckObject) {}` of `facebookCheckEmail()`, how do I do that ?

```
private void facebookCheckEmail( String email ) {



    fbCheckEmail_params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    fbCheckEmail_params.put("Email", email);

    final GsonRequest<FbCheckObject> gsonRequest = ApiRequest.gsonFacebookCheckEmailRequest
            (
                    new Response.Listener<FbCheckObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(FbCheckObject fbCheckObject) {


                            try {

                                System.out.println("Status = " + fbCheckObject.getStatus());

                                if (new String(fbCheckObject.getStatus()).equals("ok") == true) {

                                    fbresponse = "ok";

                                } else if(new String(fbCheckObject.getStatus()).equals("no") == true){

                                    fbresponse = "no";

                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                Log.d("Web Service Error", e.getMessage());
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // Deal with the error here

                        }
                    },
                    fbCheckEmail_params
            );

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(gsonRequest, TAG);

}
```

my container class is :

```
public class MainLoginActivity extends Activity {

  public String fbresponse = "";

      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     .......
    }

    ..........

    private void facebookCheckEmail( String email ) {
    ......
    }



}
```

NOTE: Inside the "`@Override public void onResponse(FbCheckObject fbCheckObject) {}`", `fbresponse` value is successfully assigned to "`ok`" or "`no`" if unsuccessful, but anywhere outside that scope if I `System.out.printIn` `fbresponse`, I will get "`null`"

Comment: You do change the variable as far as  I can see. Or is it not compiling? What isn't working as expected

Comment: when I System.out.println()  fbresponse outside of new Response.Listener<FbCheckObject>() {} Scope it returns "null"

Comment: Something is missing in the code example. You are assigning a blank to the variable and then you are changing it to "ok" or "no". I dont see where a NULL should be assigned to the variable.

Comment: it is null after I change it from fbresponse = ""; to fbresponse;

Answer (score 0):

Doing what you want is not a good design. You should rather change your method so that it returns the status:

```
private String facebookCheckEmail( String email ) {
...
}
```

And set the return value to the response:

```
fbresponse = facebookCheckEmail(email);
```

Comment: can you show me an example with the above code please?